# double-wrapping an element in jQuery

Tags: jquery

Sirs,

I've been double-wrapping my elements in jQuery for a while now *(see line 3 - the $($unitUsers[i]) part)*, so that I can call further jQuery functions on each element.

```
var $unitUsers = $('li.unit_user');
        for(var i=0; i< $unitUsers.length; i++) {
            var id_str = $($unitUsers[i]).attr('id');
```

But now it seems there must be a cleaner way. Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it is hard to tell what else is going one from only the 3 lines shown. But if you have an index to a jquery object matching a set of elements, the result is the native element.

Which is to say, this works

```
var id_str = $unitUsers[i].id;
```

If you have other needs to have access to the full jQuery API, and you wish to not "double wrap" you can use [`.eq`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)

```
var $unitUsers = $('li.unit_user');
for(var i=0; i< $unitUsers.length; i++) {
 var id_str = $unitUsers.eq(i).attr('id');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('li.unit_user').each(function(){
   alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Comment: That is a lot of alerting :D Why not use the native api? `this.id`.

Comment: @TravisJ OP should see the outputs  just a way for him to be sure this outputs are he looking for ..  and I used to use jquery $(this).attr('id') that's all  :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) like this:

```
var $unitUsers = $('li.unit_user');
$unitUsers.each(function() {
    var id_str = $(this).attr('id');
});
```

Comment: Thanks. .each was a good option too, but I needed to recall the .eq function for other purposes as well.